# Как работает viewBox?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

С viewport – все понятно. Это просто видимая область svg.
С viewBox немного запутано получается: если viewBox больше – изображение меньше, если viewBox меньше – изображение больше. Почему?
Если, как я понимаю, значения viewBox указываются в пикселях (это же не просто процентное соотношение, а определенное значение).
Вот, например:

```css
.facebook_logo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  outline: 1px double red;
}
```

```html
<svg display="none">
            <symbol id="facebook">
                <path d="M8.258,4.458c0-0.144,0.02-0.455,0.06-0.931c0.043-0.477,0.223-0.976,0.546-1.5c0.32-0.522,0.839-0.991,1.561-1.406
                 C11.144,0.208,12.183,0,13.539,0h3.82v4.163h-2.797c-0.277,0-0.535,0.104-0.768,0.309c-0.231,0.205-0.35,0.4-0.35,0.581v2.59h3.914
                c-0.041,0.507-0.086,1-0.138,1.476l-0.155,1.258c-0.062,0.425-0.125,0.819-0.187,1.182h-3.462v11.542H8.258V11.558H5.742V7.643
                h2.516V4.458z"/>
        </symbol>  
</svg>


<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="facebook_logo logo_footer">
                <use xlink:href="#facebook"></use>
</svg>
```

Тут даже на глаз видно, что картинка не 20*20. Чего я не понимаю? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: готовлю ответ. Это хороший вопрос!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT хорошо, ждём))))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это наверное один из самых фундаментальныx вопросов по SVG.
Кто понимает, как работает `viewBox`, как взаимодействует `viewport` с `viewBox`, у тех отпадает половина вопросов типа:
почему обрезается изображение, почему изображение не масштабируется при изменении размера родительского контейнера, или при смене гаджета, почему исчезает изображение и т.д и т.п

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас немного cложный пример, так как используется два svg.
Для более легкого понимания я сделаю ваш код немного проще.

```css
.facebook_logo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  outline: 1px double red;
}
```

```html
<div class="facebook_logo">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
             
                <path id="facebook" d="M8.258,4.458c0-0.144,0.02-0.455,0.06-0.931c0.043-0.477,0.223-0.976,0.546-1.5c0.32-0.522,0.839-0.991,1.561-1.406
                 C11.144,0.208,12.183,0,13.539,0h3.82v4.163h-2.797c-0.277,0-0.535,0.104-0.768,0.309c-0.231,0.205-0.35,0.4-0.35,0.581v2.59h3.914
                c-0.041,0.507-0.086,1-0.138,1.476l-0.155,1.258c-0.062,0.425-0.125,0.819-0.187,1.182h-3.462v11.542H8.258V11.558H5.742V7.643
                h2.516V4.458z"/>
        
</svg>
</div>
```

В случае если не указан `viewport`, а это `width` и `height` в шапке svg файла, то изображение занимает либо 100% экрана, либо наследует `width` и `height` родительского контейнера. В этом примере размеры для родителя `.facebook_logo` width: 500px;
height: 500px;

Изображение увеличивается в 25 раз, так как исходное изображение имеет размеры `20 х 20 px`  `viewport / viewBox` или `500 / 20 = 25 раз`

Другими словами 1px `viewBox` растягивается на 25 px `viewport` поэтому и происходит увеличение изображения в 25 раз.

Если бы был указан размер viewport   width="20px" height="20px" равный viewbox="0 0 20 20", то иконка не изменилась бы в размерах, так как `viewport / viewBox = 1`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="border:1px solid red;">
             
                <path id="facebook" d="M8.258,4.458c0-0.144,0.02-0.455,0.06-0.931c0.043-0.477,0.223-0.976,0.546-1.5c0.32-0.522,0.839-0.991,1.561-1.406
                 C11.144,0.208,12.183,0,13.539,0h3.82v4.163h-2.797c-0.277,0-0.535,0.104-0.768,0.309c-0.231,0.205-0.35,0.4-0.35,0.581v2.59h3.914
                c-0.041,0.507-0.086,1-0.138,1.476l-0.155,1.258c-0.062,0.425-0.125,0.819-0.187,1.182h-3.462v11.542H8.258V11.558H5.742V7.643
                h2.516V4.458z"/>
        
</svg>
```

либо указаны те же размеры в родительском контейнере

```css
.facebook_logo {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  outline: 1px double red;
}
```

```html
<div class="facebook_logo">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
             
                <path id="facebook" d="M8.258,4.458c0-0.144,0.02-0.455,0.06-0.931c0.043-0.477,0.223-0.976,0.546-1.5c0.32-0.522,0.839-0.991,1.561-1.406
                 C11.144,0.208,12.183,0,13.539,0h3.82v4.163h-2.797c-0.277,0-0.535,0.104-0.768,0.309c-0.231,0.205-0.35,0.4-0.35,0.581v2.59h3.914
                c-0.041,0.507-0.086,1-0.138,1.476l-0.155,1.258c-0.062,0.425-0.125,0.819-0.187,1.182h-3.462v11.542H8.258V11.558H5.742V7.643
                h2.516V4.458z"/>
        
</svg>
</div>
```

Но при указании фиксированных размеров иконка не будет масштабироваться при изменении размера дисплея.

Чтобы получить масштабирование, необходимо указывать размеры в процентах или в относительных единицах

```css
.facebook_logo {
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class="facebook_logo">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
             
                <path id="facebook" d="M8.258,4.458c0-0.144,0.02-0.455,0.06-0.931c0.043-0.477,0.223-0.976,0.546-1.5c0.32-0.522,0.839-0.991,1.561-1.406
                 C11.144,0.208,12.183,0,13.539,0h3.82v4.163h-2.797c-0.277,0-0.535,0.104-0.768,0.309c-0.231,0.205-0.35,0.4-0.35,0.581v2.59h3.914
                c-0.041,0.507-0.086,1-0.138,1.476l-0.155,1.258c-0.062,0.425-0.125,0.819-0.187,1.182h-3.462v11.542H8.258V11.558H5.742V7.643
                h2.516V4.458z"/>
        
</svg>
</div>
```

[Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/718079/28748)

Для более глубокого вхождения в тему статья на нашем сайте:
[Как взаимодействуют между собой viewport и viewBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748)

и [тут](http://svg-art.ru/?p=5) ещё можно почитать с подробными объяснениями, действующими иллюстрациями

Comment: Большое спасибо за такой подробный и ПОНЯТНЫЙ ответ)))

Comment: @Eva Благодарю. Всегда рад помочь